# Django: ORDER BY DESC on FloatField puts null values top?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm surprised to find that an ORDER BY DESC query on a FloatField in Django returns null fields higher than fields with positive values.

```
# In models.py
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
# In views.py
    cities = City.objects.filter(country__id=country.id).order_by('-value')
# In template.html
    {% for city in cities %}{{ city.name }}: {{ city.value }} --{% endfor %}
```

I get back the following:

```
  London: None -- Paris: None -- Berlin: 84.0 -- Tunis: 15.0 --
```

Instead, I want to return all the entries in descending order, with the None values last (i.e. Berlin, Tunis, London, Paris). Any way to do this?

Comment: Maybe the following Q/A helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749216/django-order-by-date-but-have-none-at-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Django doesn't make any assumption about ordering of NULLs. Different SQL databases handle that ordering differently - SQLite/MySQL put NULLs at the top, Oracle at the bottom (for ascending ORDER BY clauses). So that's probably a problem with Django not "abstracting away" these differences.

But in most use cases, it doesn't make sense to include NULLs in sorted query results. If you really have a use case where you need it, you should probably sort manually (i.e. after making the query).