# Django: copy and manipulate a QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to re-order a Django queryset, because I want to put [None values at the bottom of an ORDER BY DESC query on a FloatField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566939/django-order-by-desc-on-floatfield-puts-null-values-top).

Unfortunately, I'm struggling to find an elegant way to manipulate a Django queryset. Here's what I have so far:

```
cities = City.objects.filter(country__id=country.id).order_by('value')
if cities.count() > 1:
    cities_sorted = cities
    del manors_sorted[:]
    for city in cities:
        cities_sorted += city
        # Add code to 
        cities = cities_sorted
```

Currently, this fails with `'QuerySet' object does not support item deletion`.

Any idea how I can copy and re-order this QuerySet to put None items last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queryset will be evaluated to a list, if you eg. call `list()` on it:

```
cities_sorted = list(cities)
```