# django ordering with a blank date field

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.8 and python 2.7.

I have a model that lists the start and finish date of the users employment details.

I am wanting to [order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#orderingg) the model details using the following ordering:

```
ordering = ['-start_date', '-finish_date', 'id']
```

The issue is that the start date can be blank. When I use the above ordering, the blank start dates appear first, and I would like them to appear last in the order.

I have searched SO & Google for an answer and I am struggling to get this working.

**How do I achieve this ordering?**

Here is my model data:

```
class Employment():
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    finish_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-start_date', '-finish_date', 'id']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Order By Date, but have "None" at end?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749216/django-order-by-date-but-have-none-at-end)