# Django: sort by related model with multiple criteria, put nulls last

Tags: django, django-orm

So this super long query *almost works* as needed:

```
context['user_artists'] = Artist.objects.filter(users=current_profile) \
            .prefetch_related(Prefetch('release_groups',
                                       queryset=ReleaseGroup.objects.filter(release_date__isnull=False,
                                                                            release_date__gte=startdate)
                                       .order_by('release_date'), to_attr='rgs')) \
            .annotate(next_release=Max('release_groups__release_date')).order_by(F('next_release').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

Basically, this puts all the nulls last, BUT - since I want the SOONEST next release, this doesn't work. It puts first the FARTHEST next release.

What I need is this order:

1. Artist X - next release date: 6.12.18
2. Artist Y - next release date: 6.31.18
3. Artist Z - next release date: Null

What I'm getting is:

1. Artist Y - next release date: 6.31.18
2. Artist X - next release date: 6.12.18
3. Artist Z - next release date: Null

Comment: But then you sort the values in *asceindg* order.

Comment: I don't mind how I sort the values behind the scenes as long as I get the desired output. Nor does the user. He wants to see the upcoming releases, soonest first, farther next, and nulls last.

Comment: Maybe this is not working for annotated value. Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36188789/641249

Comment: @neverwalkaloner that looks promising but the query there seems to be not valid...? what connects the queries for `Work_Order` and `MyModel` there?

Comment: @zerohedge I suppose you can use only second query with MyModel.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I have just tried this but it "unflattens" and shows multiple entries per artist. So it's showing 1 entry per release-group, not just 1 entry per artist..which is too many.

Comment: @zerohedge can you post your query?

Comment: [there it is](https://pastebin.com/6PqXAjqj) trying to follow the answer you linked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173069/discussion-between-neverwalkaloner-and-zerohedge).