# Advanced queryset sort ordering - won't order as I would like

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to get a queryset to order in a specific way and can't figure out how to do it.

First I'd like it to order by descending `end_date` - with any empty `end_date` records grouped first.

Then the list should be ordered by the `primary` field, followed by descending `amount`.

```
queryset = MyModel.exclude_denied.filter(user=user).order_by(
        "end_date", "primary", "-amount"
    )
```

This is what I currently have but it doesn't quite return it as I'd like it.

I want the groups to appear something like this:

- Items without `end_date`

  - `primary` items listed first, then ordered by desc `amount`
- Items with `end_date`

  - `primary` items listed first, then ordered by desc `amount`

I'm trying to achieve a queryset like this:

```
ItemA - end_date:None - primary:True
ItemB - end_date:None - primary:False
ItemC - end_date:None - primary:False
ItemD - end_date:08/10/2018 - primary:True
ItemE - end_date:07/10/2019 - Primary:False
ItemF - end_date:06/08/2018 - Primary:False
ItemG - end_date:04/16/2017 - Primary:False
```

Is trying to create this order just using `order_by` the appropriate approach? I feel like it's close - but not quite there.

I am thinking a better approach would be to create 2 Querysets, then merge them together keeping their order in place.

Something like this:

Queryset1 = items without `end_date`, descending `primary`, then descending `amount`

Queryset2 = items with `end_date` (desc), descending `primary`, then descending `amount`

Combine the two Querysets but keeping Queryset1 items listed in order first, then Queryset2 items listed.

I'm not sure the best way to accomplish that though, but I'm thinking this would be the best solution.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Comment: You never mentioned what exactly is wrong with your initial approach.  Is it the objects with null `end_date` which are out of order?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749216/django-order-by-date-but-have-none-at-end

Comment: It's not clear whether "with end_date" should be ordered by end_date or not, First it seems yes, but when you explain what you want it doesn't seem that way anymore. Are there multiple items with the same end_date which should be ordered by primary, amount **after** they have been sorted (and grouped) by end_date?

Comment: @dirkgroten - yes, there can be multiple items with the same end_date that should be ordered by `primary`, then `amount` *after* they have been sorted/grouped by end_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [F() to sort null values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values), something like this:

```
queryset = MyModel.exclude_denied.filter(user=user).order_by(
    F("end_date").desc(nulls_first=True), 
    "primary", 
    "-amount"
)
```

### Update

After some comment back and forth, and re-reading your question, it occurs to me that you don't really want to sort on the *value* of `end_date`, but only whether it is null or not.  There may be a better way to convert `end_date is NULL` directly to a boolean, but I think this should work:

```
from django.db.models import Count

queryset = MyModel.exclude_denied.filter(user=user).annotate(
    num_end_date=Count("end_date")
).order_by(
    "num_end_date",
    "primary", 
    "-amount"
)
```

Comment: Good answer, but this was already the case in Django 1.11 (and probably earlier), even though this example wasn't documented.

Comment: There is the potential of some of this data to have `" "` as the end_date, which causes an error: `'' value has an invalid date format` ... so this approach doesn't quite get me there. It's close though, upvoted because I think if the data was a little cleaner, this would be a good approach.

Comment: I cleaned up the data - and this works - HOWEVER - if an element is marked as `primary` but has an older `end_date`, this order fails to put the Primary element at the top of the group.

Comment: @dirkgroten: thanks.  I was going off the docs because I couldn't remember if it was around before that

Comment: @Hanny: your last comment makes me think that you are not looking to sort in the order (`end_date`, `primary`, `-amount`).  Maybe you should modify your initial question with a list of objects and the exact order you want them to come out in.

Comment: @Hanny you're contradicting yourself again (hence my earlier question): if sorting should be on "end_date" as first sorting key (which you confirmed in your comment above), then you can't have "primary" at the top of the group. Which group? You said, first sort by end_date, then inside each group with same end_date, sort by primary. So older end_date always will be after more recent end_date.

Comment: Sorry - I apologize - I updated the question with a list of what I am trying (poorly) to explain via text. I hope that makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: hmm, I updated the answer to take `end_date is NULL` as the first sort criterion, but from your update it looks like you still want `end_date` value in the ordering... something like `("num_end_date", "primary", "end_date", "-amount")`?

Comment: @RishiG - yes, that is perfect. That does exactly that. I had just stumbled upon the annotate functionality when you made that edit. Perfect. Thank you!