# Django users last login = NULL ordered in different way between local and production

Tags: python, django, sql-order-by

I have this ListView which returns a list of users ordered by last_login.

```
class ListaUtentiOrderedByLastLogin(StaffRequiredMixin, ListView):
   model = EmailUser
   context_object_name = "lista_utenti"
   template_name = "emailusers/lista_utenti.html"
   paginate_by = settings.PAGINATION_NUM

   def get_queryset(self):
      if self.kwargs['order'] == "asc":
         return EmailUser.objects.order_by('last_login',Upper('last_name'), Upper('first_name'), Upper('email'))
      else:
         return EmailUser.objects.order_by('-last_login',Upper('last_name'), Upper('first_name'), Upper('email'))
```

Locally users are ordered with last_login NULL < NOT_NULL so in descending case users not yet logged are at the bottom of the user list.
But in production NULL > NOT_NULL and same users are at the top of the list.

Locally I use squlite db and the webserver included in manage.py
Production:
postgresql + gunicorn + nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify how to order with `nulls_first=True` or `nulls_last=True` with [**`.asc(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.asc) or [**`.desc(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.desc), for example:

```
from django.db.models import F

return EmailUser.objects.order_by(
    F('last_login').asc(nulls_last=True),Upper('last_name'), Upper('first_name'), Upper('email')
)
```

this will add a clause that looks like:

```
ORDER BY last_login IS NOT NULL, last_login, …
```

and thus force nulls to be placed last.

Comment: Thanks Willem that solve!
I see this solution also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749216/django-order-by-date-but-have-none-at-end.
But why the returns are different between develop and production? It depends from different db?

Comment: @MarcoGiuliani: yes, there is no uniformity among databases how to order `NULL`, so if it is not specified it might depend on the exact database how it is retrieved.